# Hashtable(int) more specific than Hashtable(Map)

Tags: scala

I'm curious why the error occurred:

```
scala> import collection.JavaConverters._
import collection.JavaConverters._

scala> val m = Map("one"->1)
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(one -> 1)

scala> val jm = m.asJava
jm: java.util.Map[String,Int] = {one=1}

scala> val hm = new java.util.Hashtable(jm)
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.util.Map[String,Int]
 required: Int
       val hm = new java.util.Hashtable(jm)
                                        ^

scala> import java.util._
import java.util._

scala> val hm: Dictionary[String,Int] = new java.util.Hashtable(jm)
hm: java.util.Dictionary[String,Int] = {one=1}
```

The original question is [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21495117/1296806)

It's too late at night here to review overloading.

Incorrect speculation:

It must choose between constructors taking int or a collection. It looks like, for a polymorphic method, the method with a more specific result type is more specific.  Perhaps, `Hashtable<K, V>()` is more specific than `Hashtable<String, Integer>` because there could be `<K,V>` more specific than `<String, Integer>` but not vice-versa.

No, that's not right:

```
implicitly[Hashtable[String,Integer] <:< Hashtable[_,_]]
```

The ctor is actually

```
public Hashtable(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> t)
```

Comment: I don't know why it can't figure it out, but it's possible to tell it how to do it: `new java.util.Hashtable[String,Int](Map("one" -> 1).asJava)` runs for me.

Comment: Can also do `val hm: java.util.Map[String,Int] = ...`

Comment: Looks like a bug with polymorphic Java classes, overloading, and probably more. Try minimizing an example to isolate from `j.u.HashMap`.

Comment: As I've said before, if @retronym is helping out on SO, then some really important work isn't getting done.  Unless this is the moral equivalent of retronym's water cooler.  I'll try to minimize and compensate the time suck.

Comment: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8227

Comment: Gah! Does the man never sleep? @retronym

Comment: @DanGetz thx, you can see that at the last line of the code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the ticket written up by retronym](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8227), when type inference fails for the desired constructor, overloading resolution resolves to use the other constructor that takes one value parameter.

Given:

```
package rawj;

public class C<K, V> {
    public C(C<? extends K, ? extends V> other) { }
}
```

then the type inference failure becomes visible:

```
scala> new rawj.C(null)
<console>:8: error: inferred type arguments [?1,?0] do not conform to class C's type parameter bounds [K,V]
              new rawj.C(null)
              ^

scala> val c: rawj.C[Int,Int] = new rawj.C(null)  // supply type args
c: rawj.C[Int,Int] = rawj.C@483d5954
```

If there is another constructor for C with the same shape (takes one arg), then this error is swallowed while it picks one.

There is no compiler option to ask it to explain why a particular overload was selected.

Comment: Kind of lame that there's a cooling-off period before I can accept this answer. Why does SO even display the check-mark with roll-over telling me to click it?